# Multiple buttons switch

Tags: javascript, button, switch-statement

I want to remove the style for the box which is .widget when I click the button which is .edit-one-button. I have six boxes and six buttons. When I was trying to use the javascript below. Clicking one button will remove the style for all boxes. What should I do so that it only affects the box the button resides in when I click it?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var divheight;
     $(".edit-one-button").click(function () {
      var btnname = $(this).val();
      if (btnname == 'Edit') {
        divheight = $('.widget').attr('style');
        $('.widget').removeAttr('style');
        $(this).nextUntil('.edit-one-button').toggle();
      }
      else {
        $(this).nextUntil('.edit-one-button').toggle();
        $('.widget').attr('style', divheight);
      }
    });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="eq-height2 widget>
        <header>
        <h2>Contact1</h2>
        </header>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edit-one-button/> 
        <fieldset id="Fieldset1">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="Fieldset2">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
    </div>

<div class="eq-height2 widget>
        <header>
        <h2>Contact2</h2>
        </header>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edit-one-button/> 
        <fieldset id="Fieldset3">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="Fieldset4">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
    </div>

<div class="eq-height2 widget>
        <header>
        <h2>Contact3</h2>
        </header>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="edit-one-button/> 
        <fieldset id="Fieldset5">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="Fieldset6">
          blabla
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$('.widget').removeAttr('style');
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('.widget').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: It works. However, when I click the button the second time, the style was not reset to its original. Do I need to change something about the else statement?

Comment: It's probably better to use jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function to add and remove a style rather than removing the attribute. You can also try changing `$('.widget').attr('style', divheight);` to `$(this).closest('.widget').attr('style', divheight);`

Comment: It didn't find the style of the .widget of itself but the first .widget on the page :(

Comment: I'd need to see your HTML to go any further.

Comment: There aren't any `style` attributes in the code you posted for `$('.widget').removeAttr('style');` to remove.